# What are good resources for learning and implementing photogrammetry?

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, photogrammetry

What are some good resources (videos, textbooks, etc.) to learn photogrammetry (and other related technologies) for modern and accurate techniques for 3d reconstruction?

I've seen the following:

- [Intro to Modern Photogrammetry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471309249)
- [Photogrammetric Computer Vision](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LXFI2XF)
- etc.

But I'm not sure which resources are the best to start as a beginner and move forward to learn, implement (code), etc. various promising techniques.

Comment: What's wrong with all the ones who downvote this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If you look for computer-vision based photogrammetry, which is fast but not accurate [mm/m scale], then go for "Multiple View Geometry In Computer Vision" from Andrew Zissermann. Almost all modern CV programs use methods from his book. You can find the book source-code [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/code/). It's written in MATLAB which is almost pseudocode.

If you look for slow but very accurate [µm/m scale] industrial photogrammetry, such as close-range or aerial photogrammetry, you can read something from Thomas Luhmann "Close-Range Photogrammetry", Clive Fraser, Armin Gruen, Karl Kraus and few other authors. It does not matter if it's an old book. The methods have not changed much since then. Once you have some good base, you'll be able to adapt to new methods quick.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative post. I'll be going through these resources.